# Is re-opened or re-open?

Tags: past-tense

I am trying to tell a friend that a shop has been opened again -so it had been closed before- some days ago. I am not sure which of the following sentences is the right one:

1. The shop is re-opened!
2. The shop is re-open!
3. Another sentence

Would you help me?

Comment: It's not a matter of opinion. *The shop is re-open* is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welll ....

You can say, "The shop is re-opened!" That is using "re-opened" as an adjective.

I think a native speaker would be more likely to use "re-open" as a verb in a sentence like this, and say, "The shop was re-opened." Note that if it is open now, it must have been re-opened at some time in the past, so you must use the past tense. If it is presently in the process of opening again, you can say, "The shop is re-opening".

You can't say "the shop is re-open". That's just wrong. "Re-open" is not an adjective, and it is the wrong tense to use as a verb here.

By the way, you could also say, "The shop is open again".

Comment: +1. @santimirandarp: **is re-opening** would mean that it is going to re-open soon or is now taking steps to re-open.  **re-opened** is an adjective formed from the past participle and refers to an *achieved state*, not to something which is in progress.  The shop is already doing business again. It has finished the preparations and its doors are open to customers once again.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yes, exactly.